# Retorno 'undefined' no html para requisição de objetos JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api, request, fetch

Estou tentando retornar objetos JSON de uma api, só que quando os elementos são renderizados no HTML, o valor passa para undefined. Acredito ser alguma coisa com a requisição no appenChild, já que ele retorn os objetos estilizados normalmente.

```js
// Botão busca
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn-busca");
btn.addEventListener("click", getEstadias);

function getEstadias() {

    fetch("https://api.sheety.co/30b6e400-9023-4a15-8e6c-16aa4e3b1e72")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {

            // Lista de estadias
            let listEl = document.querySelector(".container-cards");

            let imgItem = document.createElement("div");
            imgItem.classList.add("image");
            // Criando o elemento para armazenar a foto da estadia
            let imgEl = document.createElement("img");
            imgEl.setAttribute("src", data.photo);  
            // Criando o tipo de estadia
            let tipoEl = document.createElement("span");
            tipoEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.property_type));
            tipoEl.classList.add("etiqueta");
            // Adicionando os itens ao container da imagem do item
            imgItem.appendChild(imgEl);
            imgItem.appendChild(tipoEl);

            // Criando texto e preço
            let infoItem = document.createElement("div");
            infoItem.classList.add("texto");
            // Criando depoimento
            let textEl = document.createElement("h3");
            textEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.name));
            textEl.classList.add("depoimento");
            // Criando preço
            let precoEl = document.createElement("p");
            precoEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.price));
            precoEl.classList.add("preco");
            // Adicionando os itens no container do texto do item
            infoItem.appendChild(textEl);
            infoItem.appendChild(precoEl);

            // Criando o card
            let card = document.createElement("div");
            card.classList.add("card");
            card.appendChild(imgItem);
            card.appendChild(infoItem);

            // Colocando todos os elementos dentro do card
            listEl.appendChild(card);

        });
}
```

```html
<!-- BOTÃO PARA CHAMAR OS ITENS -->
<button class="component btn-busca" type="submit">Buscar</button>

<!-- CONTAINER DOS CARDS -->
<main>
   <div class="container container-cards">
    
   </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O retorno `data` é um array de objetos, onde cada objeto possui um índice. Fazendo apenas, por exemplo, `data.photo` irá retornar `undefined` porque o objeto `data` retornado no fetch não possui a propriedade `photo`.

Como é um array de objetos, você tem que iterar eles, e pode usar `forEach` pra isso, passando na função o mesmo nome `data` para não ter que renomear todos os `data` de onde você quer pegar as propriedades:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn-busca");
btn.addEventListener("click", getEstadias);

function getEstadias() {

    fetch("https://api.sheety.co/30b6e400-9023-4a15-8e6c-16aa4e3b1e72")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {

            data.forEach(function(data){
               // Lista de estadias
               let listEl = document.querySelector(".container-cards");
   
               let imgItem = document.createElement("div");
               imgItem.classList.add("image");
               // Criando o elemento para armazenar a foto da estadia
               let imgEl = document.createElement("img");
               imgEl.setAttribute("src", data.photo);  
               // Criando o tipo de estadia
               let tipoEl = document.createElement("span");
               tipoEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.property_type));
               tipoEl.classList.add("etiqueta");
               // Adicionando os itens ao container da imagem do item
               imgItem.appendChild(imgEl);
               imgItem.appendChild(tipoEl);
   
               // Criando texto e preço
               let infoItem = document.createElement("div");
               infoItem.classList.add("texto");
               // Criando depoimento
               let textEl = document.createElement("h3");
               textEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.name));
               textEl.classList.add("depoimento");
               // Criando preço
               let precoEl = document.createElement("p");
               precoEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.price));
               precoEl.classList.add("preco");
               // Adicionando os itens no container do texto do item
               infoItem.appendChild(textEl);
               infoItem.appendChild(precoEl);
   
               // Criando o card
               let card = document.createElement("div");
               card.classList.add("card");
               card.appendChild(imgItem);
               card.appendChild(infoItem);
   
               // Colocando todos os elementos dentro do card
               listEl.appendChild(card);

            });
        });
}
```

```html
<!-- BOTÃO PARA CHAMAR OS ITENS -->
<button class="component btn-busca" type="submit">Buscar</button>

<!-- CONTAINER DOS CARDS -->
<main>
   <div class="container container-cards">
    
   </div>
</main>
```